# How do I pass arguments to Main Application Class using Jemmy in JRuby?

Tags: java, swing, jruby, jemmy

I'm automating a Swing GUI application using JRuby and Jemmy library. The application takes arguments when launching. I was able to launch the application from command line by passing the arguments after the Main Class name. Is there a way to do the same using Jemmy in JRuby?

From command line

> java -cp CLASSPATH org.sample.MainApplication arg1 arg2

From Jemmy documentation

> ClassReference newApp = ClassReference('org.sample.MainApplication');
> newApp.startApplication();

What I've tried in JRuby

> main_app = ClassReference.new('org.sample.MainApplication')
>
> main_app.start_application()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial & error I figured out the issue. I was sending incorrect format for arguments.

> main_app.start_application(['arg1','arg2'].to_java(:string)) did the
>   trick.